# Parsing a string that contains multiple symbols results in crash

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, string-parsing

Im trying to split some characters in Java that contains `","` , `":"` and `"-"`

For instance ,

if the input is  `58,1:2-4`, it should produce the following output

1. Booknumber: 58
2. Chapter Number: 1
3. Verses = [2,3,4] (since 2-4 is the
   values from 2 to 4)

Following is the code that I have tried,

```
private int getBookNumber() {
        bookNumber = chapterNumber.split("[,]")[0];
        return Integer.valueOf(bookNumber);
    }

    private int getChapterNumber() {
        chapterNumber = sample.split("[:]")[0];
        verseNumbers = sample.split("[:]")[1];
        return Integer.valueOf(chapterNumber);
    }

    private List<Integer> getVerseNumbers(String bookValue) {
        List<Integer> verseNumList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (bookValue.contains("-")) {
            //TODO parse - separated string
        } else {
            verseNumList.add(Integer.valueOf(bookValue));
        }

        return verseNumList;
    }
```

I would invoke them in the following manner sequentially

```
int chapterNumber = getChapterNumber(); 
int  bookNumber    = getBookNumber();
List<Integer> verseNumbers  = getVerseNumbers(this.verseNumbers);
```

But Im getting                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "58 , 1 " in the line  `int chapterNumber = getChapterNumber();`

is there an efficient way to parse this string ?

Comment: you could use a RegEx with grouped for each of your inputs and if it matches the input is valid and you can extract the inputs easily

Comment: You mean Matcher?

Comment: yea a Pattern and then the corresponding Matcher to a specific String, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, check this sequence `^(\d+),(\d+):((\d+)|([\d]+-[\d+]))$` over at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change getChapterNumber like this:

```
private int getChapterNumber() {
    chapterNumber = sample.split("[:]")[0];
    verseNumbers = sample.split("[:]")[1];
    return Integer.valueOf(chapterNumber.split("[,]")[1]);
}
```

---

But the best would be to use matcher:

```
String line = "58,1:2-4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+):(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
group 1: 58
group 2: 1
group 3: 2-4
```

Comment: First solution works like a charm...Second solution is awesome... i will try that now...thank you so much

Comment: Bro...u r such a genius..second method is perfect and the best

Answer (score 0):

I might approach this using base string methods to avoid the heavy equipment which comes with a regex matcher:

```
String input = "58,1:2-4";
int commaIndex = input.indexOf(",");
int colonIndex = input.indexOf(":");
int bookNumber = Integer.valueOf(input.substring(0, commaIndex));
int chapterNumber = Integer.valueOf(input.substring(commaIndex+1, colonIndex));
String verseString = input.substring(colonIndex+1);
String[] verses = verseString.split("-");
int startVerse = Integer.valueOf(verses[0]);
int endVerse = Integer.valueOf(verses[1]);
int[] allVerses = new int[endVerse - startVerse + 1];
for (int i=0; i < allVerses.length; ++i) {
    allVerses[i] = startVerse + i;
}
```

Comment: Regex would have lots of time complexity?

Comment: I'm assuming you are parsing some biblical texts.  If you are certain that you will always be parsing the same pattern for references, and that it will never change, I might consider my answer as an option.  From a code readability and maintenance point of view, the answer given by @Lega is the way to go.

Comment: I would expect my answer to possibly run faster than using a regex, but the code priority outweighs this in my opinion.